# Check for network error in cf ic login in Bluemix

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I am trying to use IBM containers and I am getting the following error when I try the command 'cf ic login'

```
Deleting old configuration file...
 Retrieving client certificates for IBM Containers...
 Storing client certificates in /root/.ice/certs/...

 Storing client certificates in /root/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/9ffac48d-4bb7-4f01-a2cc-3a6b4fd64404...

 OK
 The client certificates were retrieved.

 Checking local Docker configuration...
 OK

 Authenticating with the IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net...
 OK
 You are authenticated with the IBM Containers registry.
 FAILED

 Error getting response, check your network connection
```

Can some one suggest where am I going wrong?
I am able to successfully log in bluemix using the cloud foundry 'cf login' command. However, cf ic login command fails.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a successful login, I see in that sequence:

```
Authenticating with the IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net...
OK
You are authenticated with the IBM Containers registry.
Your organization's private Bluemix registry: registry.ng.bluemix.net/yournamespacehere
```

Two thoughts - first, is the namespace (i.e. your registry name) set?  Try `cf ic namespace get` to see if that works.  Second, perhaps try doing a `cf ic init` one time to regenerate the login certs and repush them against the registry (access to which appears to be the step that's failing there).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried cf ic init. I am getting the following error now



Authenticating with the IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net...
FAILED
The attempt to authenticate with the IBM Containers registry host registry.ng.bluemix.net was unsuccessful.
****Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.13.
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v1/users/: dial tcp: lookup registry.ng.bluemix.net on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46097->127.0.1.1:53: i/o timeout

Comment: Ah!  Ok, the ips that you're getting there are NOT the correct ips for registry.ng.bluemix.net.  An nslookup for me shows something like 198.23.117.106.  127.0.anything is going to be a loopback address.  Are you going so some sort of proxy or VPN such that it's trying to route you through 127.0.1.1?

Comment: Yes i was going through a proxy at workplace. I tried at home network (no proxy) so I am able to go through this step now. I am also able to load the Fortran container image to the bluemix repository. Thank you for the help. :)